# Get names of the arguments passed indirectly to a function

Tags: r

I want to write a custom print function for an S3 object and get the desired outcome below using just the object's name. How can I achieve this?

```
print.Foo <- function(x, ...) {
  cat(paste0(x, "  (passed 'print' via ", deparse(substitute(x)), ")"))
}


boo <- 16
boo
#> [1] 16
class(boo) <- "Foo"

# sub-optimal outcome
show(boo)
#> 16  (passed 'print' via object)
```

Desired outcome:

```
# print(boo)
#> 16  (passed 'print' via boo)
```

I want the following call to give me the desired outcome above:

```
boo
#> 16  (passed 'print' via x)
```

I tinker with the following functions but could not make them work:

```
setMethod(
  f = "show",
  signature = "Foo",
  function(object) {
    cat(paste0(object, "  (passed 'show' via ", deparse(substitute(object)), ")"))}
  )

show.Foo <- function(object) {
  cat(paste0(object, "  (passed 'show' via ", deparse(substitute(object)), ")"))
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't quite work because names point to object values, but object values don't actually know their names. The connection is one way. You can look at the call stack to see what was passed, but the REPL in the R console uses a special function to call `print()` and doesn't pass the variable name you type. Nameless objects appears in containers like lists and it's unclear what `print()` should show in that case.  Sometimes multiple names may point to the same object. Are you just trying to remind the user the name of the variable they just typed?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the underlying mechanism. 
I want to use this feature to provide user a command that user can easily copy and then paste to the console. Something like: 
`cat(paste0("You can use '", deparse(substitute(x)), "^2' to calculate the square of this object.\n"))`

Comment: The `substitute()` trick only works on promises before they are evaluated. In the console, the expressions are evaluated before they are printed. There's no way to get the expression that was evaluated at the console when then the implicit `print()` is invoked. It works with `print(boo)` because both the function and parameter are evaluated at the same time (and you bypass the implicit `print()` call). It doesn't seem possible to do what you are asking. This is not for all functions, only the implicit `print()` that is called at the console.